# Regex escape match on newline character (\n)?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am have a string of multilined text as follows:

```
" 1.0.0\nProduct ID: 050-105-SX\n asdfasdfadssffa324-\dfadsfasdfasdf\n
```

And I'd like to get the following output:

```
050-105-SX
```

I'd like to do this with escapes, but can't seem to find the ability to escape on `\n` newline because the escape is of course being interpreted as two literal characters:

what I tried:

```
(?<=Product ID:\s)([^n]*) which would escape up to the "n":
```

output:

```
050-105-SX\
```

A sample on regex101 to play with is [here](https://regex101.com/r/yP9gA5/1)
(Again, I just want that string after the "Product ID".)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use \s to signify any whitespace including CRs

Comment: Are you sure you have linebreaks? Because `\n` in a VB.NET string is a literal `\` and `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
(?<=Product ID:\s)([^\\]*)
```

Comment: worked! thanks. Any idea how to explain why the newline character won't ever be recognized? Thanks!

Comment: because "\n" is interpreted as string, not as newline character

Comment: if you were reading a multiline file, each line break would be a newline character. I'm not sure if I'm being clear.

Comment: thanks, @davcs86 makes sense. The escape brackets `[]` are looking at literal character strings